# How to generate nested textboxes on runtime with different v-model on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to vuejs. I am trying to generate nested textboxes on run time on a button click event. Please check jsfiddle link for better understanding
https://jsfiddle.net/avi_02/qLqvbjvx/

Let's assume like this to understand the problem.

`++` -> It generate `MainTextBox`

`+` -> It generate `SubTextBox`

When I click on `++` then a new `MainTextBox` generates with a `+` link for `SubTextBox`
But when I click on `+` to generate a `SubTextBox` then it gets generated on all other `MainTextBox`.

I want to generate `SubTextBox` for respective `MainTextBox` only not for other main textboxes. 
Please follow jsfiddle link for visual understanding.

Comment: I am trying to implement it with two dimensional arrays but that is also not working, please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `rowsMain` needs its own array of components.

```
addRowMain() {
  this.form.rowsMain.push({
    key: '',
    value: '',
    componentRows: []
  });
}
```

And then you could add the component rows like:

```
addRowMainComponent(index) {
  this.form.rowsMain[index].componentRows.push('')
}
```

It still needs work, but see this updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qLqvbjvx/5/

Comment: Thanks @Alex . I'll carry on from hereafter.